# How can I save XML::Simple to Hashes? The XML is changed, so cannot base one attr to use

Tags: xml, perl

I have a dump from [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) when using [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'web' => {
        'cmd' => {'sw_package' => ['test_zipfs', 'test_ini']},
        'bsp' => {
            'dir'      => '.',
            'type'     => 'uc',
            'dir'      => 'soft/web/bsp',
            'test_ini' => 'lan'
        },
    },
    'world' => {
        'cmd' => {'undef' => 'undef'},
        'bsp' => {
            'dir'  => '.',
            'type' => 'hale',
            'dir'  => 'soft/hel/bp'
        },
    },
};
```

I want to copy `{web} -> {cmd}` to a hash and the same for `bsp`. I know can access the last stage of elements `{web} -> {bsp} -> {dir}`. But the XML is blind, meaning that I won't know exactly which elements it has. So I want only copy and save a hash.

I tried:

```
my $cmd = Dumper($data -> {web} -> {cmd});
my %cmd_hash = %$cmd;
```

But when use a loop through new hash `%cmd_hash` nothing happens, it doesn't print out anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to make a deep copy of parts of the hash. There's lots of ways to do this; my preference is the `Clone` module.

```
use Clone qw(clone);
my $cmd_copy = clone($data->{web}->{cmd});
my $bsp_copy = clone($data->{web}->{bsp});
```

What you're doing doesn't work because Dumper produces a string, which you're then trying to use as a hash reference. If you have `use strict 'refs'` enabled then you'd get a warning like `Can't use string ("cmd") as a HASH ref` when you tried to dereference it.

Comment: my $cmd_copy = $data->{web}->{cmd};
my $bsp_copy = $data->{web}->{bsp}; 
# Reference to hash
my %bsp_hash  =  %{$bsp_copy};
my %cmd_hash    = %{$cmd_copy}. It can work as well, the return is a hash. I did wrong when use Dumper, it returns string. thanks

Comment: The important thing to be aware of when using your method there is that you're doing a shallow copy. If you change any of the deeper values you'll see that change in both hashes. Clone will make a deep copy. Which you use depends on what you're doing with the data.